# Show that weighted least squares estimator for a specific model is not consistent

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimators

Here is the background for this problem:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$ $Y_{1},...,Y_{n}$ iid $N(\mu,c^2\mu^2)$, $\,\,$  $c^2$ known.
$\,$
The problem is as following:
Consider the above model. Define $\hat{\mu}_{WLS}$ as that value of $\mu$ minimizing

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$ $\rho (\mu)=\sum_{i=1}^n \Big\{\frac{(Y_{i}-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2\mu^2}\Big\}$.

1. Show that $\hat{\mu}_{WLS}$ converges in probability, but that its limit is not $\mu$.
2. Find $E\{\rho'(\mu)\}$ and show that it is not equal to zero.

I did part 1 by doing differentiation but failed to solve out the WLS estimator.

Comment: Consider adding a [`self-study`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag.

Comment: (1) Presumably "$\sigma$" means "$c$". (2) If you failed to find the estimator, then you probably computed the derivative incorrectly, because the estimator has a simple form. It may help to write $$\rho(\mu)=\frac{1}{c^2}\sum_i\left(\frac{Y_i}{\mu}-1\right)^2.$$ Eventually you should be able to write the estimator in the form $\hat\mu=m + \cdots$ where $m$ is the sample mean and $\cdots$ is a term that obviously converges to a nonzero value.